# Android Studio Error while importing eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I started my android development with Android Studio so I do not know much about eclipse. A client has sent me his source code for an android app that needs editing and while trying to import it I am getting the following error.

[image]

Some one please guide me to a solution, I really need it right now. 
Using android studio 2.1.2 with JDK 8 installed.

This is the project.properties file
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing a library, add the lib and it will work fine. The relative path of the lib was on C:\Users...\Desktop\.....\....\Library. Or go ahead and build your project, you will get dependency issues, solving those will resolve your pain!

Comment: The latest Eclipse release has better Android support, if you have to use Eclipse

Comment: @Skynet android studio wont allow me to build the project and like I mentioned the source code was sent to me by a client. Please see the other image I just added

Answer (score 0):

Ok so turns out the app was using a "pullToRefresh" library that was missing as a deliverable to me. I did not have an experience of working with external libraries yet so took me some time to identify that.

I downloaded the library and gave it the correct path in "project.properties" file. Then simply imported the project to Android studio and it is working absolutely fine